# SQL Server datetime field issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, regional-settings

My personal computer is running Windows 7 (language turkish) and I installed SQL Server 2008. When I create a new database, the database language is Turkish_CI_AS

And I have a server with Windows Server 2003 (language english) and installed SQL Server 2008 on that server. I set the Regional and Language Options as Turkish. I am creating a database and selecting collation Turkish_CI_AS

But when I insert a row into a table on the server, an error occurrs:

> The date format is invalid

Comment: **SHOW US** how you're inserting that row!

Answer (score 0):

You should always use unambigious formats like YYYYMMDD or YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS so that no matter what setting the server/database is it will be added correctly. Read this for a better understanding http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10898/understanding-datetime-column-part-ii.aspx

Comment: But I can insert same values in my personal computer. the properties are setted same. But server not execute query. the inserted date time formats are same as well (YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS).